# chessboard + standalone

Tags: standalone, chess, chessboard

It seems that `chessboard` when compiled with standalone, truncates the sign that indicated whose move it is. How could I make sure that the sign gets displayed without problems?

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{moreenum}
\begin{document}
\chessboard[%
    setwhite={Qa1,Qd2},%
    showmover=true,%
]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When you define a smaller mover with `moversize=1ex` the complete mover is shown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can enlarge the right margin of the board (the default value is 1em):

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{moreenum}
\begin{document}
\chessboard[%
    setwhite={Qa1,Qd2},%
    showmover=true,%
    marginrightwidth=2em
]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround you could increase the `border` on the right side, i.e. `\documentclass[border={0pt 0pt 2mm 0pt}]{standalone}`. The four values are for the left, bottom, right and top sides, respectively. (To have the same border on all sides supply just one value, e.g. `border=2mm`.)

```
\documentclass[border={0pt 0pt 2mm 0pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{moreenum}
\begin{document}
\chessboard[%
    setwhite={Qa1,Qd2},%
    showmover=true,%
]
\end{document}
```